# Microphone not working after Upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I know there have been plenty of threads like this. However, the solutions seem highly specific and I've tried most of them to no avail. I upgraded my laptop from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, which worked completely fine except that now my microphone is not detecting sound anymore.

The device is correctly detected, but does not show any reaction upon noises. Also, it doesn't matter if I try to use the inbuilt mic or the one from my headset. Sound output works as expected and switches devices.

Alsa information: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=a44f0c72ea171e9295dcab1afeaddb1daacf7ac1

What I have tried to fix it? Everything listed in this article: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure